# Background image exceed the #wrap div

Tags: css, background-image, responsive

I've a website with a #wrap div centered in the page with attribute { margin: 0 auto; }

My Cover image should take all the body in width (exceeding the #wrap) and 780px in height.

The image doesn't start form absolute point 0 on the left because the #cover div is inside the centered #wrap div.

How can I resolve this problem?

My HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">

    <div id="cover"></div>

</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#wrap {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

 #cover {
        background-image: url(bg.jpg);
        background-attachment: fixed; 
        background-clip: border-box; 
        background-position: center; 
        background-repeat: no-repeat; 
        background-size: cover; 
        height: 780px; 
        z-index: -10;
    }
```

Comment: Please, provide the necessary HTML code to reproduce your issue.

Comment: "My Cover image should take all the page in width and 780px in height."
Please clarify: Should the image be the width of the `body` or the `#wrap`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its unclear what you are trying to achieve. From the description of your problem it *sounds like* you want a fixed, full-width background. There are many ways to achieve this. In this case you should position the `#cover` absolutely and give it a 100% width and a fixed height of `780px`.

I've used percentages in this example, purely so it will fit better in the snippet window. I've also made the `#wrap` taller and given it a semi-transparent background-color so you can see the fixed nature of the `#cover` background.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
#wrap {
  width: 80%;
  height: 120%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  z-index: 1;
}
#cover {
  background-image: url(https://placekitten.com/300/300);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-position: top left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 78%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -10;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
<div id="cover"></div>
  Lorem ipsum sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.
</div>
```

FYI. For the sake of code clarity you shouldn't put the `#cover` element inside the `#wrap` unless you want/expect it to be bound by it in some way. In your case the `#cover` and `#wrap` elements are positionally unrelated as the `#cover` is supposed to be a background to the whole page not just the `#wrap`. I'd move it out just for clarity but the fix is the same regardless.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your background position is from x=0 and y=0 you need to set `background-position: top left` and not `center`. With the `background-size: cover` you are telling that the background should cover all the div, so with the left position you can loose parts from the right and from the bottom.

The solution:

```
#cover {
    background-position: top left; 
}
```